# XML file write issue

Tags: c#, xml

I am trying to append child to a XML file using the below code

```
string controlFolderPath = string.Empty;
var currentPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
if (currentPath.Contains("\\bin\\Debug"))
    currentPath = currentPath.Replace("\\bin\\Debug", "");
else if (currentPath.Contains("\\bin\\Release"))
    currentPath = currentPath.Replace("\\bin\\Release", "");

string strFilename = currentPath + "\\InitialSetup\\ClientList.xml";

XmlDocument xDoc = new XmlDocument();
xDoc.Load(strFilename);


var node = xDoc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("./Client[@Name='" + clientName.Trim() + "']");
if (node != null)
{
    MessageBox.Show("The entered Client Name already exists.");
    return false;
}


XmlElement clientElement = xDoc.CreateElement("Client");
clientElement.SetAttribute("Name", clientName.Trim());
xDoc.DocumentElement.AppendChild(clientElement);
xDoc.Save(strFilename);


MessageBox.Show("Client " + clientName.Trim() + " added in system");
```

However I keep getting error stating **"The Process cannot access file as it is used by another process"**

Can someone please help me with the error?

Comment: Please pay more attention to your formatting in future - the code was massively indented for no reason, requiring users to scroll it horizontally to see most of it.

Comment: Error message is self explanatory!

Comment: @JonSkeet Yes I will follow that.Thanks

Comment: @RahulSingh Yes I know that it is self explanatory,but the file is not kept open.

Comment: Restart your pc and try again

Comment: It looks like you want to change the file in your project/solution by running the application from inside Visual Studio (I hope that makes sense). So is it possible that VS is the "other process" that is keeping the file open?